# Render View from AppExceptionHandler

Tags: cakephp, exception, error-handling, cakephp-2.0

I'm working with CakePHP 2.0 and want to handle a ForbiddenException.
I've followed the [example](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html?highlight=exception#create-your-own-exception-handler-with-exception-handler) explained at the CakePHP Cookbook.

My exception is now caught at the AppExceptionHandler but I don't know how to move from here. I want to render a relevant View but `$this` is not available.
Does anyone have a starting point for me?

**Edit:**
My code so far is identical to the Cookbook example:

In app/Config/core.php

```
Configure::write('Exception.handler', 'AppExceptionHandler::handle');
```

In app/Config/bootstrap.php

```
App::uses('AppExceptionHandler', 'Lib');
```

In app/Lib/AppExecptionHandler.php

```
class AppExceptionHandler {
    public static function handle($error) {
        if($error instanceOf ForbiddenException ){
            echo 'Oh noes! ' . $error->getMessage();
            // $this->Session->setFlash('To access the page please login');     
        }
    }
}
```

regards,
Bart

Comment: Mind posting your AppExceptionHandler so we can see what you've done thus far?  It's worth noting that if you only need to do rendering, you can use AppExceptionRenderer, which has access to the view system via $this->controller.

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks. I've added the code but I think your remark about the AppExceptionRenderer is what I need.
In the meantime I found that I also can add the file View/Errors/error400.ctp and control the rendering of the 401 and 403 error that way.

Comment: @Brelsnok Can you please paste your latest solution about this issue. I also try to use custom error handler but can't succeed because cookbook is very limited..

Answer (score -2):

As you mentioned on your comment, you can make copies of the error views to your own `View` folder and control the rendering.

If you want to use the session as well, remember that, in any part of your application, you can use `CakeSession` to access the session as well.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html#reading-writing-session-data

Comment: I hate it when people downvote without a comment/explanation. It'd help me and others understand why some think this is not a good answer.

Comment: even more annoying is that there are 2 downvotes yet no other answer besides this one. Makes me wish I could downvote a person's downvote :-P