# CakePHP AppExceptionHandler and views

Tags: php, cakephp, exception, error-handling, cakephp-2.0

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644352/render-view-from-appexceptionhandler) and this [cookbook section](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#create-your-own-exception-handler-with-exception-handler).
I created such code and made this steps:

In app/Config/core.php

```
Configure::write('Exception.handler', 'AppExceptionHandler::handle');
```

In app/Config/bootstrap.php

```
App::uses('AppExceptionHandler', 'Lib');
```

In app/Lib/AppExceptionHandler.php

```
class AppExceptionHandler {
    public static function handle($error) {
        $errorCode = $error->getCode();
        if ($errorCode == 404) {
            header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        } elseif ($errorCode == 500) {
            header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
        }

        echo "here is something is wrong";
    }
}
```

Everything works fine except the rendering part.
To this time I can only write "something is wrong" but I can't make it viewed inside a view file.

Inside "App/Controller" folder I have "ErrorsController.php".
I need to run ErrorsController when I get an exception. So I will render inside that controller's view files.

1. How can I redirect user to ErrorsController ? Of course I can make it with redirect command. But when I redirect user to ErrorsController::index() function and when I send 404 headers inside ErrorsController, I am redirected to handler page again.
2. Where should I set response headers ? Should I set it inside ErrorsController or from handler ?

**Edit:**

```
class ErrorsController extends AppController {
    function beforeFilter() {
        if ( isset($this->request->params['pass'][0]) ) {
             if ($this->request->params['pass'][0] == "404") {
                $this->response->statusCode('404');
            }
        }
    }


    public function index($typeOfError) {
        echo "here I am $typeOfError";
    }
}
```

When I enter to `example.com/errors/index/404` the output is "here is something is wrong" but I need it to be "here I am 404". Because when I enter to ErrorsController's action and send 404 header, I am redirected to AppHandler's handle. So how can I render my own view?

This problem is still exists..

Comment: Please read My blog : http://chetan4cake.blogspot.in/2012/06/exception-handling-in-cakephp-20.html

Comment: That seems related with ExceptionRendering rather than Handling..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590614/throwing-a-custom-503-exception-in-cakephp-2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644352/render-view-from-appexceptionhandler